# HTML/CSS/JavaScript approach for flex-sizing cells by row and column

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, css-position, css-grid

```
-----------------------    -----------------------    -----------------------    -----------------------
| 1 |        2        |    | 1 |                 |    | 1 |        2        |    |                     |
-----------------------    -----                 |    -----------------------    |                     |
|   |                 |    |   |                 |    |                     |    |                     |
| 3 |        4        |    | 3 |        4        |    |          4          |    |          4          |
|   |                 |    |   |                 |    |                     |    |                     |
-----------------------    -----                 |    -----------------------    |                     |
| 5 |        6        |    | 5 |                 |    | 5 |        6        |    |                     |
-----------------------    -----------------------    -----------------------    -----------------------
```

Those are four crude drawings of the layout of my web page.  The leftmost drawing has all the data cells visible.  It has 3 rows and 2 columns.

The top row is a header, the middle row is content, and the bottom row is a footer.

The left column is a sidebar with three blocks of controls and the right column is content + part of the header and part of the footer.

I want to hide the entire header and/or footer (2nd drawing), but I also want to be able to hide only the middle row of the sidebar column (3rd drawing).  In both cases I want the remaining content to fill the open space, as in a flex container. I also want to hide everything but the content (4th drawing), but that is not difficult once I solve the other two layouts.

I will use javascript to switch between these configurations.

So what is the best approach here?  It seems to me that I can do this with a CSS grid and grid areas, or I can do it with an HTML table and rowspan/colspan.  I could also do this with my existing flex layout and absolute or relative positioning of elements.  None of these approaches is as automatic as I would like, unless I'm missing something.  I was hoping CSS grid would have a way of auto-filling both rows and columns at once, but it seems to use "tracks" and orient itself either as rows or columns, not both.

Comment: Is the content in all the sections text, or do you have media in some of them (images, videos, etc?)  is the total box always going to be the height and width of the viewport? or do these sections have dynamic content that could change the height of their row and therefore the overall height?

Comment: Yes.  I manage the sizes of all the inner panes.  It's in a hierarchy of sizing, nested divs.  There is media: video, lots of svg animations.  #4 is the media pane.  The goal is to hide peripheral elements so that the media can be maximized in either or both dimensions. I am attempting this with grid now, here is the CSS: 
`grid:32px 1fr 47px / 167px 1fr;`

Comment: FWIW, this looks like it would be easier and more dynamic with flex than grid - the place where it's tricky is that you can pretty easily do either #2 or #3 - doing both with the same HTML is where it gets difficult, as you've no doubt observed. Regadless of flex or grid (or floats, for that matter), you're going to have some amount of hard coding the behavior.  My thought is that floats is actually the most flexible/dynamic because you don't need the wrapping row/column structure you do with flexbox.  I'll post an example

Comment: Yes, I have #3 layout working with flex, but I want to do both #2 & #3. And yes, I was expecting to hard code row/col numbers or "line names".  It's a simple enough layout and the full set of possibilities is small. Floats are widely disparaged these days :)  But I'm open minded and interested to see your dynamic solution. To be clear, the numbered items in the drawings are:
`#1` five buttons in a menu bar
`#2` two blocks of text in a title bar
`#3` a sidebar with controls for viewing and listening options
`#4` media pane
`#5` playback controls
`#6` media timeline navigation

Comment: I posted the example as an answer below - and yeah, I know floats aren't much in favor anymore...not saying that they generally are a good idea, but i like that in this case it prevents having to forcefully overlap/overflow other items. either way, I just enjoy this type of problem solving - where out-of-the box thinking is required.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you cannot do L-shaped areas in `css-grid`, only rectangular areas are allowed (read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)).

Therefore - it's (as far as I know) impossible to create something between your second and third layouts with `css-grid` only (you cannot simultaneously hide `3` and `2` and make `4` take their space, for example).

Second - `css-grid` is designed for sizing and positioning, not hiding items. In solutions below I used `display: none;` on *unwanted* items.

Keeping that in mind - there's a couple of ways you can make this work:

### `grid-template-areas` solution

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  --gap-size: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: var(--gap-size);
  background-color: #fbb;
}
.container {
  /* Grid consts */
  --header-height: 50px;
  --footer-height: 50px;
  --sidebar-width: 100px;
  
  height: 300px;
  grid-gap: var(--gap-size);
  border: 2px solid #555;
  padding: var(--gap-size);
  background: #ddd;
  
  /* Grid layout */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--sidebar-width) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: var(--header-height) 1fr var(--footer-height);
}
.container:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: var(--gap-size);
}
.item {
  border: 2px solid #555;
  padding: var(--gap-size);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
}

/* Grid-areas */
.item-1 {
  grid-area: item-1;
}
.item-2 {
  grid-area: item-2;
}
.item-3 {
  grid-area: item-3;
}
.item-4 {
  grid-area: item-4;
}
.item-5 {
  grid-area: item-5;
}
.item-6 {
  grid-area: item-6;
}

/* Grid-templates */
.grid-1 {
  grid-template-areas: 
    'item-1 item-2'
    'item-3 item-4'
    'item-5 item-6'
  ;
}
.grid-2 {
  grid-template-areas: 
    'item-1 item-4'
    'item-3 item-4'
    'item-5 item-4'
  ;
}
.grid-3 {
  grid-template-areas: 
    'item-1 item-2'
    'item-4 item-4'
    'item-5 item-6'
  ;
}
.grid-4 {
  grid-template-areas: 
    'item-4 item-4'
    'item-4 item-4'
    'item-4 item-4'
  ;
}

/* Hiding items */
.grid-2 .item-2,
.grid-2 .item-6 {
  display: none;
}
.grid-3 .item-3 {
  display: none;
}
.grid-4 .item-1,
.grid-4 .item-2,
.grid-4 .item-3,
.grid-4 .item-5,
.grid-4 .item-6 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid-1">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="container grid-2">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="container grid-3">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="container grid-4">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>
```

### `grid-column` / `grid-row` solution

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  --gap-size: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: var(--gap-size);
  background-color: #fbb;
}
.container {
  /* Grid consts */
  --header-height: 50px;
  --footer-height: 50px;
  --sidebar-width: 100px;
  
  height: 300px;
  grid-gap: var(--gap-size);
  border: 2px solid #555;
  padding: var(--gap-size);
  background: #ddd;
  
  /* Grid layout */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--sidebar-width) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: var(--header-height) 1fr var(--footer-height);
}
.container:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: var(--gap-size);
}
.item {
  border: 2px solid #555;
  padding: var(--gap-size);
  background: #fff;
  
  /* Centering content */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-2 .item-4 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 2;
}
.grid-3 .item-4 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
.grid-4 .item-4 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

/* Hiding items */
.grid-2 .item-2,
.grid-2 .item-6 {
  display: none;
}
.grid-3 .item-3 {
  display: none;
}
.grid-4 .item-1,
.grid-4 .item-2,
.grid-4 .item-3,
.grid-4 .item-5,
.grid-4 .item-6 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid-1">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="container grid-2">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="container grid-3">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="container grid-4">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to do any L shapes, just two-dimensional expansion of the media pane, #4 in my drawing.  I'm part way to getting this working with CSS grid, and I'm tending towards a shorthand version of your 2nd solution: `grid-area`.  There are user buttons and other UI devices to show/hide the grid cells, and javascript behind those.  I'm planning to use the `grid-area` and `z-index` properties to simulate the hiding of cells.  I also plan to use `position:absolute` for the hidden cell content so that I can auto-show it on hover.

Answer (score 0):

So, I realize this is going to sound like an old school front end guy (not completely untrue) but I think floats actually give you more flexibility in this particular instance.  Using flex, you would need to wrap each row or column, so you have a structure where items 1-6 are not all siblings...they are grouped either in two's (if rows)

```
<div class="row1">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

or threes (if columns):

```
<div class="column1">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item5"></div>
</div>
```

With grid, all can be siblings, but you have to define everything very explicitly, and do so for every layout variation...which is not necessarily bad, but if your content isn't intentionally very uniform you start getting into trouble in terms of overflow, etc.

@fen1x already did a really nice job illustrating how grid can do this, so I won't try to recreate that.

So...floats - love them or hate them, they actually handle this use case pretty well, paired with a bit of positioning (which you would also need with flexbox, but actually would be more complicated in that context.)

https://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/vYYwYKL

If nothing else, it keeps the code pretty minimal...just food for thought, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the pen.  It has its charms.  I''ll be completing my grid version today, after dealing with some other matters.  I think it will be as lean as your float method, and I probably won't need z-index after all.  The final design has the content of these cells (the panels or panes) sliding in and out via css or js animation (probably js, as I'm doing a lot of that already).  So the hidden panes will be hidden via position:absolute and a specific position just off-screen.

After I have that working, I'll take a look at your float methodology and see if it's a better fit.

Comment: I have changed course slightly, and grid is working out better than I expected.  I am now hiding the header and footer separately.  3 buttons, 3 separate sets of elements showing/hiding. It is better for the UI/UX, and it simplifies the javascript dramatically, allowing me to increment/decrement the slash-separated values in the `grid-area` property instead of setting hard-coded values.  `grid-area` is analogous to SVG `viewBox`.  A 4-element array of numbers can set the value via: `element.style.gridArea = array.join("/");`  I'll post my own answer when I have it working.

Comment: I just posted my answer based on my last comment above.  The codepen doesn't look nearly as good as my web page, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my scope slightly, and landed on a solution using CSS Grid. Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/gObOzxr

The change in scope is that there are now 3 buttons, one for each area: header, sidebar, and footer. The header and footer now hide independently.

My solution revolves around using a 4-element array of numbers to set the `grid-area` style of the media pane (#4 in my original drawing). I already treat the SVG `viewBox` attribute in a similar way elsewhere in my javascript. Because the grid area is only expanding/contracting by one row/column at a time, I can increment/decrement the appropriate value in that array of numbers.

Once the infrastructure is setup, the assignment is simple:

```
isHide == isFooter ? ++area[index] : --area[index];
element.style.gridArea = area.join("/");
```

I happen to have a lot of related infrastructure already in place, so this solution makes sense for me. My project code has fewer literals than the codepen :)

The next issue is the UI for showing a pane when all the panes are hidden, though that should be a separate question here. In the real web page (not the codepen) the buttons are in the nav bar, which can also hide.  Should there be translucent, floating buttons to restore them? What about touch vs. mouse? Should there be a way to hover and see them?